# c programming read input error checking

Tags: c, error-handling

Is there a way to make this error checking any better? Or is there something I am forgetting? I am expecting an integer then string. I added the suggestions to the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    char line[150] = {0};
    int sscanf_counter = 0;
    int num = 0;
    char string[150] = {0};
    char dummy; 

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
    {
        printf("line is %s\n", line);
        sscanf_counter = sscanf(line, "%d %s %c", &num, string, &dummy);
        printf ("sscanf_counter: %d\n", sscanf_counter);
        if (sscanf_counter == 2 && isalpha(string[0])) 
        {
            printf ("Good value: %d\n", num);
            printf ("string: <%s>\n", string);
        }
        else 
        {
            printf ("BAD VALUE: %d \n", num);
            printf ("string: <%s>\n", string);
        }
        memset(line, 0, sizeof line);
    }

    printf("Does this print? \n");

    return 0;
}
```

I didn't want 222 to be converted to a string so I added a simple `isalpha()` check to my code. I want an actual number for my first value and actual alphabet characters not numbers converted to a string for the second value.

Output with small tweak:

```
aaa aaa
line is aaa aaa

sscanf_counter: 0
BAD VALUE: 0
string: <>
111 222
line is 111 222

sscanf_counter: 2
BAD VALUE: 111
string: <222>
111 aaa
line is 111 aaa

sscanf_counter: 2
Good value: 111
string: <aaa>
```

Comment: For even better feedback, post the true input used, output seen and output expected.

Comment: @chux I updated my code. I added the small tweak of `isalpha()` check to my code.

Comment: noobprogrammer1987 `isalpha(string[0])` is not defined for most negative values of  `string[0]`.  Highly portable code uses `isalpha((unsigned char) string[0])`

Comment: @chux it is not even "highly portable", many debug CRTs on the most used signed-char platforms ;) will outright *assert* for negative values.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala can you elaborate on what your talking about?

Comment: @noobprogrammer1987 you give use **unsigned char** or `EOF` as a parameter to `is*` functions. On x86 `char` is signed by default. In MSVC C runtime library's debug version for example the code checks the range and aborts right away if the value is negative. Others will just misbehave...

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way to make this error checking any better?

`"%d"` is not specified on overflow.  Stronger error checking can be provided with `strtol()`.

`"%d %s"` does not detect extraneous extra input.

To deal with extra input and still use `sscanf()`, see below.  If `sscanf_counter == 3`, extra non-white-space input detected.

```
char dummy;
sscanf_counter = sscanf(line, "%d %s %c", &num, string, &dummy);
```

---

The test `if (sscanf_counter == ...)`  should happen *before* using the variables.

```
  printf ("sscanf_counter: %d\n", sscanf_counter);
  if (sscanf_counter >= 1) printf ("num: %d\n", num);
  if (sscanf_counter >= 2) printf ("string: %s\n", string);
```

Tip: when printing a string, consider printable sententials to help detect leading/trailing white-space issues.  (Even though these are not expected with `"%s"`.)

```
// printf ("string: %s\n", string);
printf ("string: <%s>\n", string);
```

---

OT: Rather than code magic numbers, use code that adapts

```
// memset(line, 0, 150);
memset(line, 0, sizeof line);

// while(fgets(line, 150, stdin) != NULL)
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
```

Comment: thank you. I assume adding the dummy to end of the sscanf is just for telling me if there is extra input? Does it do anything else? What do you mean by printable sententials? Thank you for the sizeof reminder. Are the parenthesis sizeof optional? I was surprised the first time I used sizeof without parenthesis and had no issues.

Comment: Does it not need the `!= NULL` at the end of the while loop?

Comment: @noobprogrammer1987 `while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))` and `while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL)` function the same,  Code per your group's coding style.

Comment: @noobprogrammer1987 `sizeof object` codes the same as `sizeof(object)`.  With _type_, must use `sizeof(type)`.

Comment: @noobprogrammer1987 Yes, `dummy` is there to detect extra input.

Comment: "printable sententials" are the `"<>"` in `"string: <%s>\n"`.  Else it is easy to miss unexpected leading and trailing white-space character in a printed string.